# Python3.7 TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I made a button to process the event using the tkinter module but it does not work and the above error appears. How should we solve it?

My environment is using the Python version 3.7, and I am using Windows 10. And the editor is using AtomEditor.

```
#-*-coding: utf-8
from tkinter import *

def ok():
    b1["text"] = "accept"
def cancel():
    b2["text"] = "확인 됨"
def bu3():
    b3["text"] = "확인 됨"
def bu4():
    b4["text"] = "확인 됨"

window = Tk()
b1 = Button(window, text="버튼 1", command=ok).pack()
b2 = Button(window, text="버튼 2", command=cancel).pack()
b3 = Button(window, text="버튼 3", command=bu3).pack()
b4 = Button(window, text="버튼 4", command=bu4).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split each button and pack into two statements:

`b1 = Button(window, text="버튼 1", command=ok)`

`b1.pack()`

because you want to assign the button to b1, not the result of the pack call (which is None)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
b1 = Button(window, text="버튼 1", command=ok)
b2 = Button(window, text="버튼 2", command=cancel)
b3 = Button(window, text="버튼 3", command=bu3)
b4 = Button(window, text="버튼 4", command=bu4)
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()
b4.pack()
```

or better :

```
b1 = Button(window, text="버튼 1", command=ok)
b2 = Button(window, text="버튼 2", command=cancel)
b3 = Button(window, text="버튼 3", command=bu3)
b4 = Button(window, text="버튼 4", command=bu4)
for c in sorted(window.children):
    window.children[c].pack()
```